# Why am I getting 'window.initMarkers is not a function'

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, jsfiddle

I'm trying to asynchronously load Google Maps using JSFiddle, but I keep getting `window.initMarkers is not a function` error.

Some one has had the same problem and they solved it by moving it outside `$(document).ready()`. But I need to use jQuery.

So does anyone know how I can accomplish this? [My fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7fykbzm/5/).

```
var map;

var GoogleMaps = {
    loadGoogleMapScript: function (callback) {
      (...)
      script.src = 'https://maps.googl...sensor=false&callback=' + callback;        
    },

    setMarkers: function (stores) {
       (...)
    }
};

function initMarkers(){
    var stores = [
        ['Store 1', 59.9136813, 10.7421917],
        ['Store 2', 59.9136287, 10.7419084],
    ];
    GoogleMaps.setMarkers(stores);    
}


GoogleMaps.loadGoogleMapScript('initMarkers');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue

change

```
function initMarkers(){ ...
```

to

```
window.initMarkers = function() { ...
```

This makes initMarkers a global function, which can be run by the "callback" in the google script that gets loaded. functions declared like this

```
function initMarkers() { ...
```

inside document.ready are not globally scoped

Comment: Hah! That worked. But why do I have to do it this way?

Comment: I added some explanation